# Exposing REST interface from a JSP/Servlet Application

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, rest, servlets

I have created a simple Web Portal using JSP/Servlets. It is connected to MySQL Database and basically the portal is just used to manage the records in the MySQL Database.

I now want to expose REST APIs for anyone to retrieve and insert information into the MySQL database.
Would I be able to do so using JSP/Servlets.

It would be great to have suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

Lets first get some short definitions:

***REST*** is an architecture design. You can read this clear explanation from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services). Today most REST services use JSON as a message format, but this is not mandatory neighter part of REST. You can have XML, images, etc.

***Servlet*** is a RESTful implementation. You can extend `HttpServlet` in Java an implement the RESTful methods (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE). Lot of people just go with POST and GET, so it is not RESTful by definition, but it do the work.

***JSP*** is not what you are looking for in this case. Its mostly designed for user interface, and is not the right approach to expose "API"s as services and such.

Now about your question, the answer is yes you *can* use Servlets, but there are better tools to implement REST today. You'll have a litte more work to set up your structure but it will be an elegant solution.

The way to go with Java is with **JAX-RS**, the Java Enterprise specification for RESTful Services. You can follow the official tutorial [Building RESTful Web Services with JAX-RS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs.htm). I highly recommend you to follow this tutorial since it will give you a good grasp over the concepts involved.

You can use **Spring** too: [Building a RESTful Web Service](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I use Jackson 2.0 with Spring and it works like a charm.

Other example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this only with servlets, but this is not a great idea, because there are a lot of good frameworks to do this.

Take a look a this link [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)